# How to sum an entire column in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a multiple CSV files like this (just one column):

```
3
4
2.3
0.1
```

Now I want to create a gnuplot bar chart that has `<filename>:<sum of the column>`.

But currently I struggle with summing up a single column:

```
plot 'data1.txt' using 0:(sum [col = 0:MAXCOL] (col)) with linespoint;
```

Comment: I just removed your EDIT explanation from the question. When editing, you can write those changes to the dedicated field "Edit Summary".

Comment: It's fine. I made it visible because I think it resulted in the answer being different from what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from @Ethan, I was able to solve my problem:

```
array files = ['data1.txt', 'data2.txt']
array SUM[|files|]
do for [i=1:|files|] {
  stats files[i] using 1 nooutput
  SUM[i] = STATS_sum
}
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
set xlabel 'File'
set ylabel 'Sum'
set yrange [0:]
plot SUM using 1:2:xticlabels(files[column(0)+1]) with boxes
```

data1.txt:

```
11
22
33
44
```

data2.txt:

```
11
2
33
4
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The command you show is summing each row rather than each column.

(1) If you can transpose rows/columns in your csv file before feeding it to gnuplot, this command would produce a plot close to what you ask for.  Note that MAXCOL is really the number of rows (not columns) in the original data file

```
  set boxwidth 0.5
  set style fill solid
  plot 'transpose_of_original' using 0:(sum [col=0:MAXCOL] col) with boxes
```

(2) Alternatively you can do the summing gnuplot by first accumulating the sums and then plotting it afterward

```
  # get number of columns
  stats 'data1.txt' nooutput
  NCOL = STATS_columns
  array SUM[NCOL]
  # get sum for each column
  do for [col=1:NCOL] {
      stats 'data1.txt' using col nooutput
      SUM[col] = STATS_sum
  }

  # Now we plot the sums in a bar chart
  set style fill solid
  set boxwidth 0.5
  set xlabel "Column"
  set ylabel "Sum"
  plot SUM using 1:2 with boxes
```

[image]

Comment: NCOLS should be NCOL

Comment: true, it should :)

Comment: I see, your example sums up every column of the input file. Thanks for the intro!